# Magento Checkout Stuck after billing information

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

Hi I know there are many threads for this problem but nothing provides solution to my problem. The checkout page redirects to cart after I click the first continue (after billing information) . Firebug tells me that the ajax response is "403 Session Expired"

Anybody faced this one in Magento?

Comment: First check your JS error console (using firebug or chrome), if you dont have any errors, then check your server error logs

Comment: @R.S Pls check my comment to the answer below

Comment: Fixed it....it was the ispeed extension. I had to reinstall it

Comment: I had the same problem. In my local it works fine, but when it goes to live, it shows session expires in billing page. Can u saywhat is the reason?

Comment: i am facing same issues.

Answer (score 2):

PHP-MCRYPT might not be installed in your server
Please check. This solved my issue

Comment: I have other magento sites running fine on the same server!

Comment: Have you tried clearing ur js error.See if conflict is there.

Comment: Its not a JS error, when u click continue on the OPC, magento uses Ajax to load the next step which suddenly started redirecting to cart(with the cart items still there). I looked into firebug console and found out that the Ajax response is : 403 Session Expired.

Answer (score 0):

In console, check your URL parameter before clicking continue in billing information. That URL might not contain `index` or `progress` parameter in it.

See the following code in `_expireAjax()` function of class `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController`

(`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`)

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getCartWasUpdated(true)
    && !in_array($action, array('index', 'progress'))
) {  
    $this->_ajaxRedirectResponse();
    return true;
}
```

Commenting out this code can solve your issue. But, instead of just commenting out the code you can try to figure out the issue with the parameter (`$action`) in your request URL.